# Arcade Expression To Enforce Field Value String Length In a Subset of Records

Tags: string, arcade

Trying to apply an attribute rule to constrain a feature to a certain length (in the below example 8 character string, yet also trying to do it over a subset of data, in which attributes of another field meet certain criteria (the Feature field)

```
if ($feature.Feature Includes("PAR", "OVERFL PAR", "SBEUtility")){return (Count(Text($feature.Name)) == 8)}
```

Essentially, I'm trying to built a definition query into the attribute rule expression to only apply the attribute rule over a portion of the dataset where certain attributes are entered, but I'm struggling with the proper syntax

Also trying to bolster the attribute rule by looking for values that are non-numeric (the field is a text field, but the attribute rule goal is to not have lettered characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of minor issues.  First, your `Includes` syntax was incorrect.  Second, you need to explicitly return `true` when the constraint doesn't apply.

```js
if(Includes(["PAR", "OVERFL PAR", "SBEUtility"], $feature.Feature )){
    return (Count(Text($feature.Name)) == 8)
} else {
  return true
}
```